# When creating a metabox do you have to create DB fields for the data?

Tags: custom-field, database, metabox

I'm just getting to grips with metaboxes for the first time and after reading up on them one of the main question i have is do you need to specify fields in the DB to store the data got input. i.e. if you had a metabox with :

- Title `<input>`
- Description `<textfeild>`
- For Sale `<boolean>`

Are they added to an existing field in the DB stored as something like json ? Or do you also have to create fields in the DB for the fields you create in the backend ? I know it seems like a weird question but after reading several articles and docs they seem just to skim across this.. which lead to me believe it wasn't required / was handled a different way.

Answer (score 3):

When adding a metabox, the metabox itself isn't saved in the database. It's loaded from the plugin code that is written, then it's up to you to fill it with appropriate values.

You don't have to create additional fields in the DB. There is a function:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
```

In your case you might do something like:

```
update_post_meta($postId, "my_custom_metabox_title", $titleValue);
update_post_meta($postId, "my_custom_metabox_desc", $desc);
update_post_meta($postId, "my_custom_metabox_forsale", $forSale);
```

This would update (or add if not already there) data in the table `wp_postmeta` which has the following columns:

- `meta_id` - table's primary key
- `post_id` - the post id
- `meta_key` - whichever key you pass in the second argument (ex: "my_custom_metabox_title")
- `meta_value` - whichever value you pass in the third argument of above function. If the value is an array or object, it will save the data as a serialized string

Once the data is in the DB, you could then use another function to get the data:

```
$customTitle = get_post_meta($postId, "my_custom_metabox_title", true);
$customDesc = get_post_meta($postId, "my_custom_metabox_desc", true);
$forSale = get_post_meta($postId, "my_custom_metabox_forsale", true);
```

The function accepts the following:

- postId - postId of the post
- metaKey(optional) - key of the metadata you want to retrieve - if left out, it will return all metadata in an associative array (the array key would map to the meta_key)
- single (boolean optional) - if set to true, it will return the first object/string based on the key. If it was serialized data, the returned object will be unserialzed. If set to false, it will return the result as an array. If only one result, the result will be in $result[0]

Comment: Good explanation +1

Answer (score 0):

A metabox is just a UI part. You can have additional/meta data without a meta box. And you can have a meta box without having additional/meta data for a post types content. You can render whatever you want in a meta box.

Metadata added to posts are handled through `get_post_meta()`, `update_post_meta()`, etc. (read in depth about meta data in other questions and answers on this site). They don't have to necessarily have a visual representation anywhere.

Post meta data is handled through the existing API (not the validation and sanitization, but the CRUD part). And the saved data is saved into the post meta table either as sanitized value or as one entry per row.